# Python: Cannot install python module "pyautogui"

Tags: python, module, pip, pyautogui

I can't install python module called "pyautogui" on windows 10 with python version 3.8

---

CMD:

```
C:\Users\Миша>pip install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.50.tar.gz (57 kB)
Collecting pymsgbox
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.8.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\CA81~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphpcf9lnw'
         cwd: C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rzx8xe3p\pymsgbox
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f8srr00j\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\CA81~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphpcf9lnw' Check the logs for full command output.
```

---

I haven't tried to do something yet because I don't understand the error. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251 might be it

Comment: @Kendoka, I haven't found solution that works for me there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. rollback pip to an older version:

   ```
   python -m pip install pip==18.1
   ```
2. install desired module:

   ```
   pip install pyautogui
   ```
3. update pip:

   ```
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   ```

P.S. this solution works for other modules too.

Answer (score -2):

From the official documentation, it is mentioned to use "pip install PyAutoGUI" (follow the proper casing).  I used the same and is working for me.

Comment: For `pip` and PyPI package names are case-insensitive so `pip install PyAutoGUI` is exactly the same as `pip install pyautogui`.