# Pip SyntaxError because user name in path is not decodeable as UTF-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pip

this is the error code:

python 3.9
박병욱 = user name

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\박병욱\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\박병욱\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph0l3na7d'
         cwd: C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ie4y8nwv\aiohttp
    Complete output (24 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-0k89makp\aiohttp.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\박병욱\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\박병욱\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph0l3na7d' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to solve the problem...
I googled, and go to the file and change something but nothing change..

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137648/5320906) work for you?

Comment: wow thanks I rolebacked my pip and worked! thanks for your answer.

Comment: ah.... there is another error...

Comment: What is the other error?

Comment: `Command "c:\users\박병욱\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\박병욱\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ihp9a1v8\\multidict\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ 박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ap31x9lr\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\박병욱\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ihp9a1v8\multidict\`