# pip throws error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install pandas library through command prompt on Windows 10. The used Python version is 3.9.0, pip version is 20.2.4.
Every time I type `py -m pip install pandas` (`pip install pandas` doesn't work at all), I get the following error:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
```

This error is probably due to fact that the operating system language is Russian.
Practically the same happens when I try to install NumPy and other libraries.
How is it possible to fix the error?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132315/python-cannot-install-python-module-pyautogui/62137648#62137648

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that.

Comment: Your Python installation is screwed up.  Have you ever been able to install modules, or has this been happening since you first tried to use Python?

Comment: I’ve never been able to install modules because of that error